# Different definitions of linkless graphs

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, embeddings

Robertson, Seymour and Thomas defined linkless embeddings of graphs as follows:
An embedding of $G$ is linkless if every pair of disjoint circuits of $G$ have zero linking number (see [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/linklsurvey.pdf)). However Kawarabayashi, Kreutzer and Mohar defined a linkless embedding to be an emmbeding of $G$ such that every pair of disjoint cycles form a trivial link (in the sense of the knot theory), i.e, each of the two cycles can be embedded in a closed 2-disk disjoint from the other cycle (see [here](http://www.imfm.si/preprinti/PDF/01070.pdf)).

Now, here is my question: Whitehead link has a zero linking number but to me it does not seem that we can enclose each of the two cycles in the whitehead link in a closed 2-disk disjoint from the other cycle? Does this mean that the two definitions are different? or I am making a mistake?

Comment: yes, those are clearly different definitions. however the distinction is irrelevant for the purposes of that second paper, since flat implies [KKM]-linkless implies [RST]-linkless implies, as shown in [RST], the existence of some flat embedding.

Comment: It seems that [KKM]-linkless implies that each component is a trivial knot, however in [RST] case one component may be nontrivial. In particular, if an embedding of a graph is [KKM]-linkless then this graph can not be too complicated, for example any embedding of $K_7$ in $R^3$ contains a knotted cycle.

Comment: That is true, but do not forget that $K_7$ is not a [RST]-linkless graph either since it has $K_6$ as a minor which is forbidden for [RST]-linkless graphs.